# Is there a metric function defined on $M_{n}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ such that the determinant function is not continuous？

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, determinant

Is there a metric function $d \colon M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, such that the determinant function $\det \colon M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is not a continuous function on the metric space $\left( M_{n}(\mathbb{R}), d( \cdot , \cdot ) \right)$?

Of course, $M_{n}( \mathbb{R} )$ can be given the metric induced by a norm. And all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent. Thus, we can prove that $\det ( \cdot )$ is always continuous on any metric space $\left( M_{n}(\mathbb{R}), d( \cdot , \cdot ) \right)$ induced by a norm space $\left( M_{n}(\mathbb{R}), \left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert \right)$ by defining a proper norm.

I want to know whether there do exist such a metric space, it cannot be a norm space.

Comment: Well can you find a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\text{Id}: (\mathbb{R}, d) \to (\mathbb{R}, d_2)$ isn't continuous? (here $d_2$ refers to the usual Euclidean metric) This might make it a lot easier.

Comment: I mean, you can take any metric space with continuum points, any bijection from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to this space and that will give you a metric on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Obviously, you can choose them in such a way that any function (except the constant) becomes discontinuous. Maybe you have some additional assumption about the metric?

Comment: @PetrNaryshkin I think your comment answers the question and it seems the OP has nothing to add. Please consider writing an answer so that this question are no longer in the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1):

*By @JohnMa's suggestion, I'm turning my comment into an answer:*

**Yes, there is.**

To construct an example, take any metric space with continuum points, any bijection from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to this space and that will give you a metric on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Obviously, you can choose them in such a way that any function (except the constant) becomes discontinuous.

Comment: Actually, I am sorry that I did not get your point. You mean that there is not a plus operation defined on $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @TeamBright, I mean that in your question you don't request any interaction between the algebraic structure of $M_n$ and the metric and thus can choose them completely independently. From this point of view $M_n$ is exactly the same as any other set with continuum points. The usual way to define a set with both algebraic structure and topology is to request algebraic operations to be continuous (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring).

Comment: If you take a metric (or any topology) which would make $M_n$ a topological space the $\mathrm{det}$ will be continuous, since the only topology on a finite dimensional is the usual one. If you ask in to be a topological ring, it will also be continuous since the matrix component $a_{ij}$ is a continuous function of matrix $A$.